# Regex for min 9 numbers

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a javascript regex to match:

- required: 9 or more numbers.
- optional: dash, forward slash, plus and space characters.
- forbidden: any other character

So far I have

```
^[0-9-+\/\s]{9,}$
```

The only problem with this (I think) is that it counts the non numeric permitted characters along to reach the minimum 9.

How can I amend it so that it only counts the numbers to reach the minimum 9?

Comment: so for example, an ssn 000-11-2222, where it's 9 digits, but 11 characters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to solve this in a single RE (not necessarily recommended, but sometimes useful):

```
^[-+\/\s]*([0-9][-+\/\s]*){9,}$
```

Or, if you want the first and last characters to be digits:

```
^[0-9](^[-+\/\s]*[0-9]){8,}$
```

That's: a digit, followed by eight or more runs of the optional characters, each ending with a digit.

Comment: `[-+\/\s]+` -> shouldn't it be `[-+\/\s]*`? The dashes are optional.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **lookahead** to check if there are 9 or more digits anywhere

```
^(?=(\D*\d){9,})[\d/+ -]+$
 --------------
         |
         |->match further only if there are 9 or more digits anywhere
```

**OR**

```
^([/+ -]*\d){9,}[/+ -]*$
```

Comment: @TimPietzcker yes indeed sir..thanks for your suggestion..edited the ans

Answer (score 1):

`^([0-9][-+\/\s]*){9,}$` should do.

Comment: This doesn't work when the first character is not a digit, while it does allow non-digits at the end.

Answer (score 0):

its simple with look-ahead

Try this pattern:

```
^(?=([^\d]*\d){9,})[0-9-+\/\s]*$
```

Comment: quantifier `{9,}` at the end is unnecessary.and this is similar to my ans..:P

Comment: if you use {9,} regex is faster than using +. cause there is no need to check look-ahead if its less than 9 characters

Comment: No, it's slower. You already did the length check in the lookahead. Why do it again?

Comment: oh.. then even using + also check length so i better use * rather than + or {9,}. am i right?